# Sum of digits is multiple of d

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Let $d>100$ be an integer. Define the set M as folllows:
$$M=\left\lbrace\overline{x_m\cdots x_1x_0}:m,x_i\in\mathbb{N},0\leqslant x_i\leqslant 9,d\left|\sum\limits_{i=0}^m x_i\right.\right\rbrace.$$
We arrange all elements of M from small to large. Let $a_n$ be the $n$-th number.

Prove that there exist infinitely many $n$, such that $a_n-nd>\sqrt{n}$.

Source: 2014 PKU high school math autumn camp, Problem 6

Attempts: If the condition is $\sum\limits_{i=0}^m x_i=d$ instead, consider the set $M_k:=\left\lbrace1,2,\dots,10^k-1\right\rbrace\cap M$ where $k>d$.

Then $|M_k|\leqslant C(d)\cdot C_k^d$ where $C(d)$ is a constant depending only on $d$ (Because there are at most $d$ positive digits). Hence, we can choose $n=C(d)\cdot C_k^d=O\left(k^d\right)$, then $a_n>10^k$. When $k$ is large enough, we have $10^k>dn+\sqrt{n}$. So $a_n>dn+\sqrt{n}$. However, when I try to generalize this argument to original problem, it fails because the largest possible multiple of $d$ is $\lfloor\frac{9k}{d}\rfloor d$ which is larger than $k$.